# How to create custom legend labels in R/Leaflet when you use the pal argument in AddPolygons

Tags: r, colors, leaflet, legend

I have a Leaflet map that colors polygons according to a previously defined `pal` function, which varies with a variable and the bins (and therefore the colors) are defined manually. Then it creates a legend using the same palette based on the same variable. All wonderful.

Unfortunately, they want a custom legend, because for example, Leaflet says "0-100,100-200,200-300" and it isn't clear which bin "200" is in. And they want NA to say "no data." Etc.

No problem, in `AddLegend` I can use `labels=c("0-99","100-199","200-299","no data")` (for example).

Except `labels` needs a corresponding `colors` vector, and I'm using `pal` to color the polygons. I can't figure out how to use 'colors' instead of 'pal' to color the polygons so I can use the same palette in the legend.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Sample code below.

```
bins <- c(0,100,200,300,400)
pal1 <- colorBin("BuGn", domain=county_map$full_risk, bins=bins)
map_widget <- leaflet(county_map) %>%

  addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,

    opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,

    fillColor = ~pal1(median_full_risk),

    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,

      bringToFront = TRUE),

    label = labels,

  labelOptions = labelOptions(

    style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),

    textsize = "15px",

    direction = "auto"), group="Median Full Risk Premium") %>%

  addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal1, values = ~median_full_risk,

    labFormat = labelFormat(prefix = "$"),

    opacity = 0.5, title="Median Full Risk Premium", group="Median Full Risk Premium")
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question! Turns out that instead of

`pal = pal5, values = ~variable`

You can use

`c(pal5(0),pal5(1),pal5(5),pal5(10),pal5(20),pal5(NA)), values = ~variable, labels= c("<1%","1-4","5-9","10-19","20+","no data")`

Where `c(0,1,5,10,20,Inf)` were the bins you defined when creating the polygons